# XML validator library

Tags: c++, xml, validation

I'm using `XML` in my application with some own XML-parser (from `ClanLib` library).

The problem : that parser can't validate `XML` and it fails if any mistakes are presented. I need some validator which will say if the `XML` is valid and (preferable) show the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) can validate XML using DTD and XSD. Syntax is also validated.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, You can use MSXML to validate an XML.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx

The validate method is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756003%28VS.85%29.aspx).

From C++, You'll have to use COM.